# Vertically Centered Text in HTML inline CSS only. (Moodle quiz)

Tags: html, moodle

I would like to have some text vertically centered.

I am writing questions in the LMS Moodle and only have access to very basic HTML in a little text box to create the question, unfortunately I don't know enough HTML. I don't think I can use any CSS in this little textbox. At least, I don't know how to. (Edit. I can use inline CSS styles, see answer below).

My end goal is to have some text next to a table with the text vertically centered with the height of the table. I couldn't find the answer to this, hopefully it is not a duplicate. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

This is what I have so far:

```html
<div>
  <p style="float: left">A&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
  <table style="float: left">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I am using `style="float: left"` so that the text and the table appear next to each other.

Comment: `style="float: left"` might be inline style but still CSS...

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of when HTML finished and CSS started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If inline styles are okay to you, then you can use `display:flex` property on parent `div` to arrange your components.

I have use `height:100vh` which uses entire page height and center the child. You can adjust according to your needs.

```html
<div style='height:100vh; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;'>
  <p>A&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
   <p>=&nbsp;A&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem. I was playing with the inline styles you suggested and it seems that using only `display:flex; align-items:center;` centers the text in the middle of the div height. `justify-content:center;` is a nice extra. I didn't specifically ask for horizontal centering but I will end up using it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your table inside another table.

```html
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A=</td>
        
        <td>
        
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          
        </td>
        
        <td> The text next to the table</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```